# DSP sound effect library for iPhone/iPad/iOS?

Tags: iphone, audio, signal-processing, soundeffect

Any 3rd party, or built in stuff?

Comment: Use the google young SO user.

Comment: I have used for about two hours now. SO comes after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the [MoMu](http://momu.stanford.edu/stk/) release of the Synthesis Tool Kit (STK) library. It has a permissive license and is lightweight, however if depends what kind of "effects" you are looking for. It has all the building blocks to do sound synthesis and processing (class documentation [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/classes.html)).

Comment: Thanks, looks promising (they should do more SEO work, though).

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use this audio DSP library for iOS/OSX: [NVDSP](http://bartolsthoorn.github.com/NVDSP/)

It is easy to use but still produces high-quality results.

It didn't exist at the time of your question, but well, I think it's the best option today. And I really don't say that just because I wrote it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 has some new built-in Audio Units for filters and some other simple effects.  Before iOS 5, it appears that most audio app developers rolled their own DSP effect libraries (or purchased a commercial time-pitch library, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://theamazingaudioengine.com/
Little late but might help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Also late, but great sound effect libraries are made by [LittleEndian.com](http://LittleEndian.com/developers)